# Extract groups of consecutive numbers in Excel list

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, sequence

Let's use this list as an example

"1,2,3,8,9,10,11,12,55,56,57"

As you can see, I have a list which generally increases in increments of one, but which often skips ahead.

In this example, I have three groups of consecutive numbers, which are 1-3, 8-12, and 55-57.

I need a formula which gives me two lists. One for the first number in each group, and one for the last.

For example, the first list would be 1, 8, and 55.

The other list would be 3, 12, and 57.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any hint on how you had actually 'Extract' the list into its component/parts?

Answer (score 1):

For this question i use:

1. Sheet1 as the primary sheet
2. Numbers appears in column A
3. Starting Numbers appears in Column C
4. Ending Numbers appears in Column D

[image]

Try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LRL As Long, LRS As Long, i As Long, j As Long, StartValue As Long
    Dim NextValue1 As Long, NextValue2 As Long, Row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LRL = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Row = 0

        For i = 2 To LRL
            If Row < i Then
                StartValue = .Range("A" & i).Value

                    For j = 0 To LRL
                        NextValue1 = .Range("A" & i + j).Value
                        NextValue2 = .Range("A" & i + j).Offset(1, 0).Value

                        If NextValue1 + 1 <> NextValue2 Then
                            LRS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                            .Range("C" & LRS + 1).Value = StartValue
                            .Range("D" & LRS + 1).Value = NextValue1
                            Row = .Range("A" & i + j).Row
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next j

            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with array formulas:

For the start of each group

```
=A2
```

in (say) C2 and

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(A$3:A$13-A$2:A$12>1,A$3:A$13),ROW()-ROW(A$2)),"")
```

in C3 and pulled down.

For the end of each group

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((A$3:A$13-A$2:A$12>1)+(A$3:A$13=""),A$2:A$12),ROW()-ROW(A$1)),"")
```

Last two formulas must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Could be refined further to work with variable number of rows.