# Is there a function to contract series or ranges of numbers in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which includes comma-separated ranges of years, which can be hard to read in other uses, e.g.:

```
1900, 1901, 1902, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, etc.
```

Ideally I would have the ranges contracted/truncated to be more legible:

```
1900–1902, 1904–1906, 1910–1915, etc.
```

How can i best achieve this in Excel?

Comment: You need to write a VBA code for that to find the gaps (non-continous numbers) and generate the number ranges. If the initial data is in only one cell then probably the `Split` function will be very useful. Note that you should try something on your own and post your attempt with a question related to what you have tried (see [ask]).

Comment: Almost similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721493/extract-groups-of-consecutive-numbers-in-excel-list)  .. See [this](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/889123-group-consecutive-numbers-in-a-concatenated-list.html)..

Comment: @NareshBhople, the difference with those links is that this question is about a single cell. Good finds nonetheless =)

Comment: @JvdV .. True. I was giving a hint for a macro.. Never thought it could be possible with excel functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it into a function, so you can use it in VBA or even as formula:

So all you need to do is split the input sequence by `", "` and loop through the numbers to test if the current number `f(i)` is consecutive to its previous numeber `f(i-1)`. If they are not consecutive you need to end the current range and start a new one.

There is only one tricky part and that is to avoid single year ranges to appear as `…, 1918-1918, …` and output `…, 1918, …` instead.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ReduceConsecutiveNumbersToRanges(ByVal InputSequence As String) As String
    Dim InputArr() As String
    InputArr = Split(InputSequence, ", ")

    Dim OutputSeqStart As Long  'current range start
    OutputSeqStart = InputArr(0)

    Dim OutputSequence As String

    'start output sequence
    OutputSequence = OutputSeqStart

    'find gaps to write ranges
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(InputArr) + 1 To UBound(InputArr)
        If Not InputArr(i) = InputArr(i - 1) + 1 Then
            'current number is not in sequence so we need to end current sequence and start a new one
            If InputArr(i - 1) = OutputSeqStart Then 'check if it is a single-year-range only to avoid outputs like `…, 1918-1918, …` and output `…, 1918, …` instead
                OutputSequence = OutputSequence & ", " & InputArr(i)
                OutputSeqStart = InputArr(i)
            Else
                OutputSequence = OutputSequence & "-" & InputArr(i - 1) & ", " & InputArr(i)
                OutputSeqStart = InputArr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'end output sequence if it is not a single-year range
    If Not InputArr(i - 1) = OutputSeqStart Then
        OutputSequence = OutputSequence & "-" & InputArr(i - 1)
    End If

    ReduceConsecutiveNumbersToRanges = OutputSequence
End Function

Public Sub TestFunction()
    Debug.Print ReduceConsecutiveNumbersToRanges("1900, 1901, 1902, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1918, 1920, 1921")
    'output will be: 1900-1902, 1904-1906, 1910-1915, 1918, 1920-1921
End Sub
```

It will reduce

```
1900, 1901, 1902, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915, 1918, 1920, 1921
```

to

```
1900-1902, 1904-1906, 1910-1915, 1918, 1920-1921
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of substitution involved but if you don't want macros involved I believe the following works:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]=.-1 and following::*[1]=.+1]"),0)),"-",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))),",-"," "))," ,","-"),",",", ")
```

If you consider two consequtive years a range and you want them concatenated by a hyphen then:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]=.-1 and following::*[1]=.+1]"),0)),"</s><s>",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[following::*[1]=.+1]"),0)),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]=.-1 and following::*[1]=.+1]"),0)),"</s><s>",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))&"</s></t>","//s")&"-",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]=.-1 and following::*[1]=.+1]"),0)),"</s><s>",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))&"</s></t>","//s")),"")),"-, ","-")
```

And yes..... That's crazy!!...but here are the results:

[image]

Please note to enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Comment: Crazy solution ^^. But it looks like is has an issue with two-year-ranges like `1900, 1902, 1903, 1905` shouldn't it return `1900, 1902-1903, 1905`? Or was this on purpose?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, hmm not sure if it's an issue to be honest. If OP considers two consequtive years a range, than you are right =). I designed it now so that it checks preceding *and* following sibling for respectively -1 and +1.

Comment: I'm not sure, too ^^

Comment: Or I might be wrong ^^ who knows. • I like the idea of doing it differently. So it is at least nice proof of concept.

Comment: Formula length `1975`  you really tried to crack the `8192` char limit ^^

Comment: I could limit it a little bit down to `951`, but still I would go with the first formula which actually is quite simple compared to the second @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Usually pure formula solutions are pretty fast. I wonder if a VBA function can beat an extensive use of nested formulas like this in speed.